# SpaceX NROL-76?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9

According to SpaceX's website, it does not announce a NROL-76 launch in mid-April. However according to other sources such as the NRO and spaceflightnow announce that a Falcon 9 will launch the satellite April 16. Since the NRO satellites are classified, and SpaceX is a private company, will the launch be shown live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The private company United Launch Alliance live broadcast the launch of NROL-79 on March 1, 2017.  (However, the coverage ended at payload fairing jettison).

So there would seem to be no reason for SpaceX not to, at least for the same portion of the launch.

Comment: Is SpaceX not allowed to publicly announce a flight will take place?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that.

Answer (score 5):

[According to a journalist and NSF writer ChrisGebhardt](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=40328.msg1659502#msg1659502):

> SpaceX confirms this will be an LZ-1 landing.
>
> Webcast will cut off launch coverage as usual for NRO missions (like
>   we see with ULA), but will continue for booster landing coverage.

For the SpaceX website - in the past the "upcoming launch" part of the manifest was often shown/updated just few days before the planned launch date. They seem to not show any info when there is still large probability of date change.